# Collection using reference equality

Tags: java, collections, referenceequals

In Java is it possible to create `HashMap` that uses reference equality (i.e. `==`) instead of the `equals()` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) class.  This is a variant of `HashMap` in which `==` and `System.identityHashCode()` are used instead of `Object.equals(Object)` and `Object.hashCode()`.

Note that this class intentionally violates the API contract of [`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which *requires* that key equality is based on `equals(Object)`.

Answer (score 1):

The [IdentityHashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) class comes with standard Java. From the JavaDoc:

> This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys (and values). In other words, in an IdentityHashMap, two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==k2). (In normal Map implementations (like HashMap) two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==null ? k2==null : k1.equals(k2)).)

Be aware that many functions that take `Map`s do so assuming that they will use `equals`, rather than reference equality. So be careful which functions you pass your `IdentityHashmap` to.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the equals method of the objects you insert into the HashMap to test reference equality.

As in:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this == obj;
}
```